# How to show AM/PM on time input in firefox

Tags: html, css

[image: Input type="time" on google chrome]

[image: input type="time" on firefox]

I need to show AM/PM on time input in firefox.

```
<input name="mondayOn" placeholder="" type="time" required="" value="06:00:00">
```

It works fine on google chrome but not on firefox.
Any solutions?

Comment: Just remove the two '0's at the end of the `value` so instead of `06:00:00` you have `06:00`

Comment: Just tried. but same

Comment: Have you tried increasing the width of the input?

Comment: oh, just tried it. it already has AM/PM. then how can I hide seconds?

Comment: The seconds are being shown because of  `value="06:00:00"` setting it to `value="06:00"` should remove them